# What will happen if I downgrade my Mac to use macOS Mojave (10.14.6)?

Tags: macos, operating-systems, macos-mojave

I want to use macOS Mojave (10.14.6) so that I can use Wine, but I heard that Apple is discontinuing support for macOS Mojave.

If I downgrade my computer, will I be unable to install update(s) from the app store, such as macOS Monterey (12.0.1), macOS Big Sur (11.6.1), etc, after the support drops?

Comment: That's a question for Apple, I think. Either that information is published and you have the same access to it we do, or it's not published, and we won't know either.

Comment: @music2myear Why is it so difficult to discern that if an OS needs to be updated, and the underlying system is still supported, Apple will let you download?

Comment: I'd balance the need for Wine against the fact that many apps are now being built for Catalina & newer. If you want to stay current on those, you might want to consider running a VM instead.

Answer (score 0):

### You should have no problems updating macOS to a newer version of macOS if you downgrade.

> “If I downgrade my computer, will I be unable to install update(s) from the app store, such as macOS Monterey (12.0.1), macOS Big Sur (11.6.1), etc, after the support drops?”

So do you want to know that I you downgrade will you be locked out from getting a newer version of macOS? That answers is “No.” If you want to upgrade in the future, you can just go to the Apple Store and select the update and that’s that.

What is lost when software enters “end of life” is that patches and security updates won’t be provided specifically for macOS Mojave (10.14.6) after that “end of life” date is reached.

Comment: oh ok, so you mean that it is the version that won't get updated. So, will we still be able to upgrade no matter what? My dad uses macOS el captain, and he can't update to mojave, or newer. That reassures me, so I can still update to monterey again!

Comment: @ABYSS Yes to everything you say. “My dad uses macOS el captain, and he can't update to mojave, or newer.” That is because whatever actual Mac machine he uses doesn’t qualify for macOS past El Capitan (10.11.6). If your own personal Mac can use macOS Monterey (12.0.1) or macOS Big Sur (11.6.1), you can downgrade your Mac to whatever minimum macOS version that system supports.

Comment: @ABYSS And a follow up to all of this… Happy to help! If you found this answer helpful, please feel free to upvote it. And if it is the answer that solved your question, please be sure to check it off as such.